# Creating a Character Array with a Certain Number of Vowels and Consonants (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, random, character

I am trying to create a program that outputs ten lowercase letter characters - five vowels and five consonants. In order to do this, I have started by creating a char array with a range between `'a'` and `'z'` called `letters[]` with size 10. Once the array is filled, I will print the output with the use of a format string containing everything in the array.

My question is, how would I make the program output exactly five of each type (and keep the order of the characters printed completely random)? I have considered using the `switch` statement with a case each for consonants and vowels, but my ideas so far seem over-complicated and inelegant.

Code so far:

```
char letters[] = new char[10];
for(int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++){ //Open for

letters[i] = (char)(97 + Math.random() * 26);
char idx = letters[i];

System.out.printf("%s",idx);

} //End for
```

Comment: Just put 5 random consonants and 5 random vowels into one array and shuffle.

Comment: Perhaps you could show us your code as I'm unclear as to how you are _filling_ your array. At a guess, perhaps you could keep a running count of how many vowels and how many consonants you have added to `letters`. Once you reach 5 for either, you stop adding that type.

Comment: I'll add my code so far to OP. It's not much, but hopefully it'll give you an idea of how I'd like to go about this.

Comment: @shmosel Is there an easy way to just shuffle the contents of the array when I print it? If so, that'd make my life a lot easier.

Comment: Look up the Fisher-Yates shuffle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind a somewhat more String-related solution, here is one. I am assuming that you don't want any consonant or vowel repeated in the output string, so this algorithm removes letters for consideration once they've been used. It also provides a bit more of a generic letter picker routine that's not really limited to vowels and consonants.

```
import java.lang.StringBuilder;

public class Shuffler {
    public static String CONSONANTS = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz";
    public static String VOWELS = "aeiou";

    /*
     * Returns a new string that is a combination of the current string and 'count'
     * characters from the source string (using any character in the source string
     * no more than one time).
     */
    public static String shuffleIntoString(String current, String source, int count) {
        if (current == null || source == null || count < 0 || count > source.length()) {
            System.out.println("Error in parameters to shuffleIntoString");
            return null;
        }

        StringBuilder retval = new StringBuilder(current);        // build up by inserting at random locations
        StringBuilder depletedSource = new StringBuilder(source); // remove characters as they are used

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            int pick = (int) (Math.random() * depletedSource.length());
            int whereToInsert = (int) (Math.random() * retval.length());
            retval = retval.insert(whereToInsert, depletedSource.charAt(pick));
            depletedSource.deleteCharAt(pick);
        }

        return retval.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shuffler shuf = new Shuffler();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            String result = shuf.shuffleIntoString("", shuf.CONSONANTS, 5);
            result = shuf.shuffleIntoString(result, shuf.VOWELS, 5);
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
}
```

And the output looks like this:

```
kqoibauzed
uhcawoerib
afdzoemius
yuagocibej
eiuhaokcyq
ouveiawrxn
uyaiveomxn
ruxeoalhij
uraliwfeoc
afoutiesmr
```

Answer (score 0):

This will achieve what you desire if you are content with using [ArrayLists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). To generate the random chars you could generate a number within the index of the corresponding char Strings and add the value to the ArrayList. [Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) is a helpful Class that you can use to shuffle the list.

```
List<Character> list = new ArrayList<>();

String consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz";
String vowels = "aeiou";

Random r = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    list.add(consonants.charAt(r.nextInt(consonants.length()))); // Add consonant
    list.add(vowels.charAt(r.nextInt(vowels.length()))); // Add vowel
}
Collections.shuffle(list);

for (Character c : list) {
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't seen any rules about duplicated but if you want you can remove latters from arrays after selection.

```
    List<Character> vowels = Arrays.asList('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u');

    List<Character> consonants = new ArrayList<>();

    for (char latter = 'a'; latter <= 'z'; latter++) {
        if(!vowels.contains(latter)) {
            consonants.add(latter);
        }
    }

    final Random random = new Random();

    int vowelsRemain = 5;
    int consonantsRemain = 5;

    List<Character> result = new ArrayList<>();

    while (vowelsRemain > 0 && consonantsRemain > 0) {
        final boolean generateVowel = random.nextBoolean();

        final char randomLatter;

        if(generateVowel) {
            randomLatter = vowels.get(random.nextInt(vowels.size()));
            vowelsRemain--;
        } else {
            randomLatter = consonants.get(random.nextInt(consonants.size()));
            consonantsRemain--;
        }

        result.add(randomLatter);
    }

    while (vowelsRemain > 0) {
        final Character randomVowel = vowels.get(random.nextInt(vowels.size()));
        result.add(randomVowel);

        vowelsRemain--;
    }

    while (consonantsRemain > 0) {
        final Character randomConsonant = consonants.get(random.nextInt(consonants.size()));
        result.add(randomConsonant);

        consonantsRemain--;
    }

    System.out.println(result);
```